# Как упаковать строку в Delphi 10?

Tags: delphi, zip

Как упаковать строку в Delphi 10 ?

```
var 
  s : string;
  z : array of byte;
begin
  s:= 'какой то текст'; // Length(s) = 14
  z:= Pack(s);          // Length(z) = 5
end;
```

Есть ли уже готовая функция, модуль, библиотека или изобретать свой велосипед?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите `TCompressionStream` из стандартного модуля `System.Zlib`. Можно сделать например вот так:

```
function CompressString(aText: string): TArray<Byte>;
var
  bytes: TArray<Byte>;
  OutputStream: TMemoryStream;
  Compressor: TCompressionStream;
  I: Cardinal;
begin
  // Get contents as bytestring
  bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(aText);

  // Compress
  OutputStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Compressor := TCompressionStream.Create(clMax, OutputStream);
    try
      I := Length(bytes);
      Compressor.Write(I, SizeOf(I));
      Compressor.Write(bytes[0], I);
    finally
      Compressor.Free;
    end;

    SetLength(bytes, 0);
    SetLength(bytes, OutputStream.Size);
    OutputStream.Position := 0;
    OutputStream.Read(bytes[0], OutputStream.Size);
  finally
    OutputStream.Free;
  end;

  Result := bytes;
end;
```